# getting error when trying to use OracleDataSource to get connection in 19c DB

Tags: java, connection-pooling

Can someone help me with the below code. It is working fine when i am connecting to Oracle 11g DB but it is failing with the error **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** when i switch to Oracle 19c DB. I am using ojdbc8.jar and  Java 8 for running the below code. In 19c database we are using the Technical account to connect to database instead of normal user account, i am not sure if that has something to do with the error as well.

```
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import java.util.Properties;
    
    
    import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;
    
    public class OracleDataSourceTest {
    
        final static String DB_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:xxxxxxx";
        final static String DB_USER = "XXX";
        final static String DB_PASSWORD = "XXX";
        
    
        /**
         * @param args
         * @throws Exception 
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            OracleDataSource dataSource = new OracleDataSource();
            dataSource.setConnectionCachingEnabled(true);
    
            dataSource.setUser(DB_USER);
            dataSource.setPassword(DB_PASSWORD);
            dataSource.setURL(DB_URL);
            Properties jdbcProperties = new Properties();
            jdbcProperties.setProperty("oracle.jdbc.thinLogonCapability", "o3");
            dataSource.setConnectionProperties(jdbcProperties);
            Properties connectionProperties = new Properties();
            connectionProperties.setProperty("MinLimit", "1");
            connectionProperties.setProperty("MaxLimit", "50");
            connectionProperties.setProperty("ConnectionWaitTimeout", "0");
            connectionProperties.setProperty("ValidateConnection", "true");
            dataSource.setConnectionCacheProperties(connectionProperties);
    
            Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
            
            System.out.println("Connection obtained");
                    
            //do some work with the connection.
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            System.out.println("Executed Stmt " + stmt.execute("select * from dual"));
            
            //Close the Connection.
            
            conn.close();
        }
    }
```

The following is the full stacktrace of the error

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
        at oracle.security.o3logon.a.a(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.security.o3logon.b.g(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.security.o3logon.O3LoginClientHelper.getEPasswd(Unknown Source)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:1238)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:1025)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:743)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:793)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:57)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:747)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:406)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:291)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:206)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:148)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:91)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleImplicitConnectionCache.makeCacheConnection(OracleImplicitConnectionCache.java:1610)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleImplicitConnectionCache.makeOneConnection(OracleImplicitConnectionCache.java:517)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleImplicitConnectionCache.getCacheConnection(OracleImplicitConnectionCache.java:477)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleImplicitConnectionCache.getConnection(OracleImplicitConnectionCache.java:363)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:513)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:202)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:184)
        at com.ubs.jdbc.connectionpool.test.OracleDataSourceTest.main(OracleDataSourceTest.java:37)
    Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
        at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
        ... 22 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating to the 19c drivers of ojdbc8. (19.18.0.0 or above)

There are many releases of ojdbc8 and many of the older ones will not support server v19c.

Link (unfold section for 19c): https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html